# Unresolved externals, Missing comdlg32.lib library

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, linker-errors, windows-ce, unresolved-external

I am working with application for WindowsCE 2013 which is partially created in WinAPI. While I tried compile the code, I met a error message "Error 2 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol PageSetupDlgW referenced in function "long cdecl WndProc(struct HWND *,unsigned int,unsigned int,long)" (?WndProc@@YAJPAUHWND__@@IIJ@Z) C:\Users\tykab\OneDrive\Dokumenty\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\WinAPI\WinAPI\WinAPI.obj WinAPI"

Problem exist with function PageSetupDlg() which is defined in commdlg.h I have no idea why this problem exist

I suppose this is because comdlg32.lib is missing.
Please confirm my assumptions and, if they are true, indicate where I can find such a library.

I put some code snippet below:

```
enter codecase WM_PAINT:
    PAGESETUPDLGW pd;
    HWND hwnd;
    ZeroMemory(&pd, sizeof(pd));
    pd.lStructSize = sizeof(pd);
    pd.hwndOwner = hwnd;
    pd.hDevMode = NULL;     // Don't forget to free or store hDevMode.
    pd.hDevNames = NULL;     // Don't forget to free or store hDevNames.
    pd.Flags = PSD_RETURNDEFAULT ;
    HDC hDC;
    hDC = CreateDC(NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    if (PageSetupDlg(&pd) == TRUE)
    {
        StartDoc(hDC, NULL);
        StartPage(hDC);
        Ellipse(hDC, 500, 500, 1000, 1000);
        Ellipse(hDC, 1000, 800, 1500, 1300);
        Ellipse(hDC, 800, 1000, 1800, 2000);
        EndPage(hDC);
        EndDoc(hDC);
        DeleteDC(hDC);
    }
    break; here
```

Comment: IIRC Windows CE does not have the `functionA` and `functionW` variations (it's been a while), just `function` - so would look at the build configuration first (assuring I am correct re the function naming)

Comment: Have you included commdlg.h and Windows.h in your .cpp or .hpp file?

Comment: @DimplePatel Yes, of course

Comment: @RichardCritten In commdlg.h is written this snip as preprocessor code:
#ifdef UNICODE
#define PageSetupDlg  PageSetupDlgW
#else
#define PageSetupDlg  PageSetupDlgA
#endif // !UNICODE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok problem was solved.
The solution is that in WindowsCE equivalent for commdlg32.lib is commdlg.lib